# CORS issue when calling API (with a self-signed certificate) via axios in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, cors

I have my React web application hosted on AWS in one cluster `https://example1.com` and I'm trying to call my API via axios in React which is hosted on a different cluster `https://example2.com/api/login` and is currently using a self-signed certificate. I want to test if everything works on HTTPS. The API is written in Java and has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header set. I get a CORS error when calling the API.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example2.com/api/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

It does not work when I test my React application on `https://localhost` as well.

My React web application is bundled using webpack. For local development I'm using webpack-dev-server and for production builds Node.js server is used **only**  to serve the pages. The Node.js server is not HTTPS. The Node.js server on `https://example1.com` is deployed for production builds via Docker on a custom port.

Other external APIs like Eventbrite, Meetup, Google Places and Google Books work fine.

Do I need to do any special configurations in React / Node.js to get this to work?

cURL gives the following error as well when running `curl -X POST https://example2.com/api/login`

```
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Running `curl -X POST https://example2.com/api/login -k` works.

Similarly, in Postman I can only get the API to work when SSL verification is turned off.

***Note:*** Everything works when all hosts are on HTTP.

Comment: Try open the URL directly in a couple different browsers and see what happens. It sounds like the reason the axios request fails is the same reason it fails when you try using curl (without the -k switch). I would think for that case the browser would log an SSL error for this in the console but maybe not.

Comment: When I open the API URL in any browser, I get the `Your connection is not secure` page where  need to add the page as an exception to proceed.

Comment: It’s not clear if you’re looking for solution you can use temporarily just for local development or whether you’re saying that the problem is something that will persist after you deploy in production. If it’s just something you need temporarily just for local development, I guess you could try starting your browser with security disabled — though I’m not sure if even that’ll cause the browser to allow insecure SSL/TLS. But regardless, if you’ll be trying serve content to users in production with a self-signed cert, then there is no solution. Or rather the solution would be to not do that.

Comment: Only for testing. For production there will be a trusted certificate.

Comment: I tried using the `rejectUnauthorized` option in a HTTPS agent similar to what was suggested here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535. I am not sure if this works in React though.

Answer (score 0):

So browser blocks request to suspicious server.

Workaround may be running server at `https://example1.com` that will just redirect requests like `/api/login` to `https://example2.com` ignoring certificate's error.

But better get trusted certificate.